# How to create a new column in a pandas Dataframe based on a value in other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

rPobably a simple question but I can't find the correct instruction to do it easily.

I have 2 dataframes with the following structure.

```
Dataframe 1
Name1 Name2  Col1   Col2     Col3    Col4
aaa   bbb    1         3       5      7
ccc   ddd    9         8       6      4
eee   fff    2        10      11     12
ggg   hhh    13       15      17     19
aaa   jjj    25       35      23     41
.
.
.

Dataframe 2
Name  ColA  ColB
aaa    100   200
ggg    300   400
eee    500   600
ccc    700   800
.
.
.
```

I need to add 2 columns to Dataframe 1 that contain the values in ColA and ColB in Dataframe 2 where Name1 in dataframe1 is equal to name in dataframe2.

To obtain the following:

```
Dataframe 1
Name1 Name2  Col1   Col2     Col3    Col4  ColA   ColB
aaa   bbb    1         3       5      7     100    200
ccc   ddd    9         8       6      4     700    800
eee   fff    2        10      11     12     500    600
ggg   hhh    13       15      17     19     300    400
aaa   bbb    25       35      23     41     100    200
.
.
.
```

Note that Dataframe1 can have several times aaa, bbb, ccc but dataframe2 have onlu one time this value

Comment: Use: `df.merge(df2, left_on='Name1', right_on='Name').drop('Name', axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
DataFrame1["ColA"] = DataFrame2["ColA"] 
DataFrame1["ColB"] = DataFrame2["ColB"]
```

This will add your Desired Columns into **DataFrame1**

Whenever you want to add a column which is not present in your DataFrame you could simply type `DataFrame_name["column_name_you_want_to_add"] = Value` to add your Desired Column to the DataFrame

Comment: Thanks but the aaa, bbb, ccc values are not in the same order in both dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={"Name": "Name1"}), on="Name1")
```

```
  Name1 Name2  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  ColA  ColB
0   aaa   bbb     1     3     5     7   100   200
1   ccc   ddd     9     8     6     4   700   800
2   eee   fff     2    10    11    12   500   600
3   ggg   hhh    13    15    17    19   300   400
```